# read implicit return type in Razor MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm kind of new to razor MVC, and I'm wondering how can I read the values I return in the view?

My code is like this:

```
    public ActionResult Subject(int Category)
    {
        var db = new KnowledgeDBEntities();
        var category = db.categories.Single(c => c.category_id == Category).name;
        var items = from i in db.category_items
                    where i.category_id == Category
                    select new { ID = i.category_id, Name = i.name };
        var entries = from e in db.item_entry
                      where items.Any(item => item.ID == e.category_item_id)
                      select new { ID = e.category_item_id, e.title };
        db.Dispose();


        var model = new { Name = category, Items = items, Entries = entries };
        return View(model);
    }
```

Basically, I return an anonymous type, what code do I have to write to read the values of the anonymous type in my view?

And if this is not possible, what would be the appropriate alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically, I return an anonymous type

Nope. Ain't gonna work. Anonymous types are emitted as **internal** by the compiler and since ASP.NET compiles your views into separate assemblies at runtime they cannot access those anonymous types which live in the assembly that has defined them.

In a properly designed ASP.NET MVC application you work with view models. So you start by defining some:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<EntryViewModel> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class EntryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and then you adapt your controller action to pass this view model to the view:

```
public ActionResult Subject(int Category)
{
    using (var db = new KnowledgeDBEntities())
    {

        var category = db.categories.Single(c => c.category_id == Category).name;
        var items = 
            from i in db.category_items
            where i.category_id == Category
            select new ItemViewModel 
            { 
                ID = i.category_id, 
                Name = i.name 
            };

        var entries = 
            from e in db.item_entry
            where items.Any(item => item.ID == e.category_item_id)
            select new EntryViewModel 
            { 
                ID = e.category_item_id, 
                Title = e.title 
            };

        var model = new MyViewModel 
        { 
            CategoryName = category, 
            Items = items.ToList(),      // be eager
            Entries = entries.ToList()   // be eager
        };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally you strongly type your view to the view model you have defined:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Model.Name

<h2>Items:</h2>
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <div>@item.Name</div>
}

<h2>Entries:</h2>
@foreach (var entry in Model.Entries)
{
    <div>@entry.Title</div>
}
```

By the way to ease the mapping between your domain models and view models I would recommend you checking out [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Oh, and since writing `foreach` loops in a view is kinda ugly and not reusable I would recommend you using display/editor templates which would basically make you view look like this:

```
@model MyViewModel

@Model.Name

<h2>Items:</h2>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items)

<h2>Entries:</h2>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Entries)
```

and then you would define the respective display templates which will be automatically rendered for each element of the respective collections:

`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/ItemViewModel`:

```
@model ItemViewModel
<div>@item.Name</div>
```

and `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/EntryViewModel`:

```
@model EntryViewModel
<div>@item.Title</div>
```

Comment: But these are temporary classes that I will use only once, I might have to redefine them later on. For example, EntryViewModel has more fields in the database, but I only need two of those fields at the moment, at an other time I might need more, do I then have to redefine that class?

Comment: @NomenNescio, you should define view models for each view. You simply cannot pass anonymous classes to views. To simplify the mapping between your domain models and view models you may checkout [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/).

Comment: I see, where should I put those views? In the Models directory right? In a directory whose name corresponds to the controller?

Comment: @NomenNescio, yeah, the Models directory is a good place. As far as the name is concerned, name them according to the view they are bound to, not the controller since a controller could have many actions dealing with many different views. Remember: you have a view model per view.

Comment: Thank you! I will check you AutoMapper when I understand razor better!